# Viewholders and setOnClickListeners

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have a `RecyclerView` with a list of items. The individual list item is an `ImageView` with a `TextView`. They have different behaviours when clicked. The individual list item is rendered with the aid of a ViewHolder.

Where should I put the `.setOnClickListener()` call for the `ImageView` and `TextView`? In the ViewHolder? Or inside the RecyclerView's `onBindViewHolder` method when the view is binded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official doc of **[ViewHold](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html)**:

> A ViewHolder describes an item view and metadata about its place
>   within the RecyclerView.

So you should avoid do anything else in the viewhold, instead use **`onBindViewHolder`** in the **`RecyclerView`**

If you take a look at the example made by **Google** of RecyclerView on [GitHub](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RecyclerView) you will see google does not set listeners in the ViewHolder

Comment: Thank you, for the example and doc links

Answer (score 1):

Call it inside of the `onBindViewHolder` method while you're binding your `ImageView` and `TextView`. If you set it on the `ViewHolder` itself, then the onClick() will be triggered for the entire list item in the RecyclerView .